# Setting up Solr and Querying it

Tags: solr, solrj, solr-query-syntax

I am new to `Solr`.

1. I am not able to find out a proper document which could help me understand what all do I need to add in the `solrconfig.xml` and what is to be removed.
2. My `SolrDocument` would contain `id, field1, field2`. Out of the 2 fields, I want to update 1 of them. How do I do? I tried a few things but it overwrites the entire document.
3. `/update` is not working.

I have to add `documents` and retrieve them from inside a `Java` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can refer to [Solr Wiki for Solr Config.xml](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml) it is a good starting point to understand the configuration options.
2. Solr does not really have an update concept, it always deletes the existing document and replaces it with new document. There is a feature request open years back [JIRA-139](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-139) to address this problem, but as of today it shows the fix version to be 4.1. But [Solr 4.0](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solr4.0) has a new feature `Atomic update` that you could try, if this is something very critical for you. Note: `Solr 4.0` is still a Beta.
3. '/update' not working -> do you mean not working since it is replacing the old document with new document or do you get error/exception ?
4. To add & retrieve documents from Java, you can use `SolrJ`. SolrJ is Java client to access Solr programmatically. [SolrJ - Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj).